# fancybox is not working for aspxgridview pages except first page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress, fancybox, aspxgridview

I'm using fancybox on my page in Aspxgridview. In first grid page, it is working correctly. When I click the grid's other pages, fancybox does not work and url is opened in new tab. I want to open hyperlink urls in fancybox popup. What can be the problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox({
            openEffect: 'none',
            closeEffect: 'none',
            showCloseButton: true,
            titleShow: true,
            transitionIn: 'elastic',
            transitionOut: 'elastic',
            width: '80%',
            heigh: '80%',
            autoScale: true,
            type: 'iframe',
            onClosed: function() {
                location.reload();
                return;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

...

```
    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="gridDX" ClientInstanceName="grid" runat="server" KeyFieldName="ID" OnDataBinding="gridDX_DataBinding" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnPageIndexChanged="gridDX_PageIndexChanged">
      <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Edit" Caption="View" VisibleIndex="1">
          <DataItemTemplate>
            <dx:ASPxHyperLink CssClass="fancybox" ID="hypShowEdit" ClientInstanceName="hypShowEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/edit.png" Text="Show/Edit" NavigateUrl="Documents.aspx">
            </dx:ASPxHyperLink>                   
          </DataItemTemplate>
        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
      </Columns>
    </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

In addition, I've a pageindexchanged method:

```
protected void gridDX_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var view = sender as ASPxGridView;
        if (view == null) return;
        var pageIndex = view.PageIndex;
        gridDX.PageIndex = pageIndex;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the fancybox initialization to a separate method and call it within ASPxClientGridView.Init (not the jQuery document.ready) and EndCallback events.

Check out the [Using jQuery / jQuery UI libraries with DevExpress ASP.NET Controls / MVC Extensions](https://www.devexpress.com/kbid=K18561) guide regarding this.

```
//$(document).ready(function () {
function InitFancyBox() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        showCloseButton: true,
        titleShow: true,
        transitionIn: 'elastic',
        transitionOut: 'elastic',
        width: '80%',
        heigh: '80%',
        autoScale: true,
        type: 'iframe',
        onClosed: function() {
            location.reload();
            return;
        }
    });
}
//});

<dx:ASPxGridView ...>
  <Columns>
    <dx:GridViewDataColumn ...>
      <DataItemTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxHyperLink CssClass="fancybox" ...>
        </dx:ASPxHyperLink>
      </DataItemTemplate>
    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
  </Columns>
  <ClientSideEvents Init="InitFancyBox" EndCallback="InitFancyBox" />
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that, when you are writing code like `$('.your selector').fancybox()`, you are attaching click event that starts fancybox on currently existing elements on the page that matches your selector. That means, if you reload page (or parts of your page) so that current elements are replaced with the new ones, you have to call `.fancybox()` again.

Comment: How can I call it again when page changed?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with .NET